# Google analytics sessions and wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, session, google-analytics

In google analytics my site have 27000+ users weekly, and 52000+ session. which is around 1.8 page view/session. There is no authentication sessions, like sign in etc, website is in word press. I want to know when user enter in site and view a page it will be considered as 1 session, but if same user lets say open page after some time then will it be new session or old?

I am using W3 Total cache and in browser cache expires header lifetime is set to 3600 seconds. Is this time related to sessions. Default word press session for login users is 48 hours, but in my scenario its anonymous user.

In google analytic definition about session is "Its the period time user is actively engaged with site".

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics has very limited information about what happens on your site. It will receive data whenever someone loads a page, and possibly when an event takes place (but only if you've set that up).

It is not informed when a user does any of the following:

- Closes the tab or browser.
- Shuts down their PC.
- Follows a link out of your website.

You could rip out the power cord of your PC mid-browse, then turn it back on. If you picked up where you left off, Google would have no way of distinguishing that from you refreshing the page.

As such, Google Analytics has to to approximate the end of each Session, with a set of rules based on the information it does have. Google will consider a session over when:

- There has been no interaction for 30 minutes (this timeout can be adjusted).
- Midnight happens (This is mainly to keep the data neat. Time Zone is defined in the settings).
- A new Session is created with a different Source, Medium or Campaign (so if you leave the site and return via a different route, this is for attribution).

Whenever you land on a site, Google Analytics perks up and takes notice. It then waits faithfully for your next hit. If you come back looking different, it'll close your old Session and start a new one. At midnight, it'll close all Sessions for everyone. Otherwise, it'll wait faithfully for up to 30 minutes. If you interact in that time, it'll excitedly update your Session and reset the 30 minute clock.

Incidentally, that's also how time on site is calculated. On your first hit, your Session is assigned 0 seconds time on site. If you interact again, that time is updated to match the time between the two hits. When your Session is closed, its final time on site is whatever the value was at the moment it was closed, so Bounces have a time on site of 0.